# conditional format with a vlookup and if statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I need help please.

I have a spreadsheet, on one tab column D has the name of a country and column K has a charge. There are 14 countries altogether.

On tab 2 I have a table with each country and a minimum and maximum cost against each (column T is country, U is minimum and V is maximum).

I need my conditional format to find the country for that row from the table in tab 2, I then however need it to highlight the cost in column k from tab 1 in blue if it goes below the value of min (column T) in tab 2 or in red if K is higher than the max.

I have tried a couple of times now but each time I seem to miss something.

Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried by using a formula in the conditional formatting? And if so, can you share that formula?

Comment: =IF(VLOOKUP(D2,Europa!$T$9:$V$22,2,FALSE),<'Export 2019'!$K$3=RED)

Comment: I have 14 countries each with a min and maximum in the Europa sheet. Each row in the Export sheet will contain at least one of these countries in. I am trying to say if column K in export is less than the minimum in Europa then highlight red. To be honest I am just trying to figure it out for the min before I include the AND for max.

Comment: I am doing this in the conditional format - new rule - use a formuala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your formula is almost correct. How about this:

`=IF(VLOOKUP(D2,Europa!$T$9:$V$22,2,False)>K2,1,0)`

The output is either 1(true) or 0(false). In this case the cell changes color if K2 is smaller than column 2 of your VLOOKUP range.

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work either, thanks for the help though. Will keep at it.

Comment: I have purposefully made my first row K price less than the minimum in the Europa tab and I changed > to < but it does not seem to be changing. Even tried it just as a normal formula in the next column and changed 1 & 0 to "High" & "Low" but just get NA

Comment: Try changing back the < to > and leave 1 and 0. If K2 is smaller than the Europatab, then Europatab > K2 is correct in this formula. It triggers when the formula is true (or 1)

Comment: Thank you shall give it a shot tomorrow.

Comment: Hey I got it thanks, it was because when I used your formula the table reference was written as $T$19 when it should be $T$9.

Comment: Thank you for your help needed some fresh eyes on it.

Comment: Glad it works. I changed my answer so it says $T$9 now, in case of future references.